# How to add the items in listview Dynamically in android?

Tags: java, android

I am adding the items in my listview, it's working fine but the listview is not expanding.

This is my code:

```
private ArrayList<NameDetails> nameDetails = null;
```

inside `onCreate()` code is

```
    nameDetails = new ArrayList<NameDetails>();
    case R.id.tvAddMore:

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.location_name_details_dialog);

                final EditText etName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etName);
                final EditText etPhone = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
                Button btnOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
                Button btnCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);


                btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        String name= etName.getText().toString();
                        String phone= etPhone.getText().toString();


                        nameDetails = new ArrayList<NameDetails>();

                        NameDetails nameDetailss = new NameDetails();
                        nameDetailss.setName(name);
                        nameDetailss.setPhone(phone);
                        nameDetails.add(nameDetailss);

                        NameDetailsAdapter nameDetailsAdapter = new NameDetailsAdapter(nameDetails);
                        lvNameDetails.setAdapter(nameDetailsAdapter);
                        nameDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });

                btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                break;









    public class NameDetailsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        ArrayList<NameDetails> nameDetails;
        String Name,Phone;
        int count  = 0;
        Context ctx;
        Activity act;
        public NameDetailsAdapter(ArrayList<NameDetails> nameDetails)
        {
             this.nameDetails = nameDetails;

        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return nameDetails.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {

             LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)MyApp.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.name_details, null);

            TextView tvName     =    (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            TextView tvPhone    =    (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
            TextView tvNameOne  =    (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNameOne);
            TextView tvPhoneOne =    (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneOne);


            NameDetails name = nameDetails.get(position);
            tvName.setText(name.getName());
            tvPhone.setText(name.getPhone());

            tvNameOne.setTypeface(AppConstants.BOLD);
            tvPhoneOne.setTypeface(AppConstants.BOLD);



            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

**NameDetails.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin15"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin15"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNameOne"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:text="@string/name"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size14" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:text=":" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin10"
                android:layout_weight="0.65"
                android:background="@drawable/text_field"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxEms="40"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding5"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding5"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size13" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPhoneOne"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:text="@string/phone_no"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size14" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:text=":" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin10"
                android:layout_weight="0.65"
                android:background="@drawable/text_field"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxEms="40"
                 android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding5"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding5"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size13" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in your XML . where is the listview ?

Comment: Whenever you add a new data, call notifyDataSetChanged(), and your listview will be updated. What notifyDataSetChanged() will do is it will tell your ListView that the data has been updated, and to refetch data in ListView

Answer (score 0):

ListView in android Does not increases dynamically. Its dimesion will be same as you have provided in your layout file(But you can scroll it). If you want to dynamically increase your ListView make it the child of scrollView and make sure the scrollView shoud go upto bottom of screen, and the hieght of listview should match parent.

Note- This is not the standard practice to do